# positive definiteness under fixed sum symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

My question follows from another of my question: [symmetric matrices and positive definiteness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3869393/symmetric-matrices-and-positive-definiteness). Suppose the matrix $A$ is symmetric with all entries positive and each row sum is a fixed constant ($>1$). Assume that each diagonal entry is greater than the off-diagonal entries of the corresponding row (and column), by atleast 1 (that is, the difference between the diagonal entry and each corresponding off-diagonal entry is atleast more than 1).
From these conditions, can we conclude that $A$ is positive definite. 
Try: I tried to write $A=sI-B$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $s$ is the largest diagonal entry of $A$ ($s>1$, from the given conditions). Then, I am not sure how to proceed. I am not sure if the result follows by gershgorin's theorem. Any hint will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a counterexample, let
$$
A =
\pmatrix
{
10  &   8   &  6   &  2 \cr
  8  &  10  &  2   & 6 \cr
  6  &    2  & 10  & 8\cr
  2  &    6  & 8  & 10
}
$$
and note that $\det(A)=-3120$.